# How to keep Python's unittest module from finding files it shouldn't?

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing

I have my code running on a Linux server.  I edit my code from my laptop which happens to be a Mac.  I use netatalk so that I can easily mount the code directory on my server from my laptop.  I recently started playing with Pyramid and SQLalchemy and I wanted to add "unittest" to my development practices.

OS X / Netatalk create a .AppleDouble sub-directory when I view any directory from the laptop.  Normally, this isn't a problem, I just ignore the .AppleDouble sub-directories.

The moment I visit the directory I'm running my tests from, OS X / netatalk add the .AppleDouble directory and in this directory, I can find files that have the exact same names as are present in the parent directory.  This is a problem because unittest recurses through all of the directories it find looking for a pattern of "test*.py" and tries to import those files.  Which fails on any file in the .AppleDouble directory (which contain icon data, desktop placement, and such).

I know that one option is not to use netatalk.  I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Looking at the code in unittest (specifically loader.py), it seems that the discovery of test cases happens in a function called discover() and a related function _find_files().

I am looking for some thoughts on how to best override the discover() and _find_files() functions.  I don't have a lot of experience overriding the Python library and I don't see any obvious hooks.

If it matters, I am using virtualenv and am pretty sure that if I put a copy of unittest in the virtualenv, it will override the system version.  That probably a good start, but I'm interested in knowing what other people think of as a better solution rather than just a good one.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run tests? If you are developing a package with `setup.py` you can tell it to look for tests in a specific package (/folder) using the testsuite parameter. Or try [nosetests](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) as a testrunner.

Another option would be to load the tests yourself, i.e.:

```
import unittest

def runtest(testclass):
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testclass)
    testResult = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```